# How is IPsec (strongswan) working without opening ports in UFW?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, ufw, strongswan

I needed to setup a site-to-site VPN between servers A and B, where server A is being managed by me and server B is being managed by a client.
Server A is running Ubuntu 20.04 and I am using strongswan to setup the VPN on my end. I am using UFW to manage server A's firewall.

Public IP address of A: `16.XX.XXX.17`
Public IP address of B: `14.XXX.XXX.94`

Now after making the necessary configuration changes for setting up the VPN and turning it on, I am able to see the following logs in `/var/log/syslog`

```
Mar 21 13:58:47 worker0 charon: 01[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr AUTH N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) SA TSi TSr ]
Mar 21 13:58:47 worker0 charon: 01[IKE] authentication of '14.XXX.XXX.94' with pre-shared key successful
Mar 21 13:58:47 worker0 charon: 01[IKE] IKE_SA s-to-s[1] established between 16.XX.XXX.17[16.XX.XXX.17]...14.XXX.XXX.94[14.XXX.XXX.94]
Mar 21 13:58:47 worker0 charon: 01[IKE] scheduling reauthentication in 2644s
Mar 21 13:58:47 worker0 charon: 01[IKE] maximum IKE_SA lifetime 3184s
Mar 21 13:58:47 worker0 charon: 01[IKE] received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
Mar 21 13:58:47 worker0 charon: 01[CFG] selected proposal: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/NO_EXT_SEQ
Mar 21 13:58:47 worker0 charon: 01[IKE] CHILD_SA s-to-s{1} established with SPIs c97fea32_i f60175ca_o and TS 10.132.86.142/32 === 10.128.28.96/27
Mar 21 13:58:53 worker0 charon: 14[NET] received packet: from 14.XXX.XXX.94[4500] to 16.XX.XXX.17[4500] (80 bytes)
Mar 21 13:58:53 worker0 charon: 14[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL request 0 [ ]
Mar 21 13:58:53 worker0 charon: 14[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL response 0 [ ]
Mar 21 13:58:53 worker0 charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from 16.XX.XXX.17[4500] to 14.XXX.XXX.94[4500] (80 bytes)
Mar 21 13:58:58 worker0 charon: 07[NET] received packet: from 14.XXX.XXX.94[4500] to 16.XX.XXX.17[4500] (80 bytes)
Mar 21 13:58:58 worker0 charon: 07[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL request 1 [ ]
Mar 21 13:58:58 worker0 charon: 07[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL response 1 [ ]
Mar 21 13:58:58 worker0 charon: 07[NET] sending packet: from 16.XX.XXX.17[4500] to 14.XXX.XXX.94[4500] (80 bytes)
Mar 21 13:59:03 worker0 charon: 05[NET] received packet: from 14.XXX.XXX.94[4500] to 16.XX.XXX.17[4500] (80 bytes)
```

Output of `ipsec status`:

```
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
   s-to-s[1]: ESTABLISHED 5 minutes ago, 16.XX.XXX.17[16.XX.XXX.17]...14.XXX.XXX.94[14.XXX.XXX.94]
   s-to-s{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP SPIs: c97fea32_i f60175ca_o
   s-to-s{1}:   10.132.86.142/32 === 10.128.28.96/27
```

The `ufw status`

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
666                        LIMIT       Anywhere                   # For ssh
62626                      ALLOW       Anywhere                   # For wireguard
Anywhere on pv0            ALLOW       Anywhere                  
666 (v6)                   LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)              # For ssh
62626 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # For wireguard
Anywhere (v6) on pv0       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**How is the server able to receive packets on 4500 port (according to the ipsec logs in `/var/log/syslog`) without me opening that port? What am I missing here?**

I have not touched IP tables directly at all.
I have verified by running a simple http server on 8000 port (using `python3 -m http.server`) that I am not able to access other unopened ports from outside the server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the log, the host is acting as client, not as server. That is, it is initiating the IKE_SA and sending the first message. Outbound connections are usually not blocked, by default. Check the default policies on your host with `ufw status verbose`.

Answer (score 1):

`ufw` is not the sole firewall module present in the system, it merely controls its own chain(s) in the global `INPUT` iptables/nftables chain. You can verify that the required rules are installed by running `iptables -S` on server A, you should see that there are some `ACCEPT` rules for UDP:4500 somewhere reachable from `INPUT`.

Alternatively, there is more than one routing/filtering table, and while `ufw` operates on "general" table (IIRC index 254) VPN systems usually allocate one of the tables with a smaller number (200 seems to be a common choice) and set up traffic that's subject to VPN control to be routed/filtered by that table. Verify by running `nft list tables`, then you can inspect a table by running `nft list ruleset table (table)`. Check with your man pages for exact syntax please.